# Creating Model with Relations in Django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

How I can set a field that

```
is_read = models.IntegerField(choices=message_status, default=SENT)
message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
read_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Here the `read_time` should be time when `is_read` becomes one

Comment: At first sight, it might be better *not* to have an `is_read` field, but simply make `read_time` `NULL`able. If it is not null, then the message is read. Right now, you have *data duplication* in your database.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your model has data duplication. Indeed, it would be possible that `is_read` is `0`, but the `read_time` is set. You can try to define views to prevent that, but that will be challenging: each view needs to be carefully written to ensure that. Furthermore you can manipulate your database outside Django.

It might be better to make the `read_time` nullable:

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=1200)
    sent_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    read_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)

    @property
    def is_read(self):
        return self.read_time is not None

    @is_read.setter
    def is_read(self, read):
        if self.read != self.is_read:
            if read:
                self.mark_read()
            else:
                self.mark_unread()

    def mark_read(self, save=True):
        self.read_time = now()
        if save:
            self.save()

    def mark_unread(self, save=True):
        self.read_time = None
        if save:
            self.save()
```

So in case you mark you mark a message as read, you save the `read_time` to the current timestamp. Furthermore we define a property `.is_read` that is `True` in case the `read_time` is not `None`. You can furthermore set `some_message.is_read = True` to update the `read_time` to now, and use `some_message.is_read = False` to set the `read_time` back to `None`.